# Django model permissions not picked up on admin

Tags: django, django-admin, django-permissions

I've added permission to my model and I would like to create a group in admin that uses this permission.

The problem is that the new permission is not listed in the permissions list.

is there something I need to do to add it to that list?

```
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ("add_remove_job", "Can add/remove jobs"),
        )
```

SOLUTION: It is a known limitation of South, the solution is to do syncdb --all

Comment: Since you found your solution, you should select the answer that gave you the solution.

Answer (score 15):

try:

```
manage.py syncdb --all
```

Otherwise, You can force django to generate permissions for a particular app:

```
from django.contrib.auth.management import create_permissions
from django.apps import apps

create_permissions(apps.get_app_config('my_app_name'))
```

This will do all models in the app. You can substitute a list of model class objects instead of 'get_models()' if you only want a subset.

Comment: Unfortunatelly doesn't work with Django 1.7 anymore. You have to `from django.apps import apps` and then call `create_permissions(apps.get_app_config('my_app_name'))` but (I think if you use migrations) it will return after `if not router.allow_migrate(using, Permission)` without doing anything.

Comment: Important the `--all` flag for apps using South! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is a syncdb each time you add/modify a permission for a model.

```
 python manage.py syncdb
```

Comment: did not work, I tried to syncdb
I'm using South for DB migration if this means something.

Answer (score -5):

```
python manage.py migrate --fake
```

Comment: How does it relate to the question?